# Angular 10 - ERROR in document is not defined

Tags: angular

I was building an app and upgraded to version 10. Everything was going well and then I suddenly get the error below and the app won't compile anymore. I have blanked every component trying to figure out just where this is coming from with no luck. I have no idea what to do now.

[image]

```
{
  "name": "mak-clean",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@ngrx/data": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.1.0",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.2",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you by any chance just access `document` instead of injecting the document via token?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It was working fine in version 8.